# Convert string to class function

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have an import called `utilities`

In this import there are two functions, `utilities.func_1` and `utilities.func_2`

Now I know I can do `print(dir(utilities))` to see the dictionary of functions this object has.  In this case it outputs

```
['PIPE', 'Popen', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'func_1', 'func_2']
```

My question is assume I have the string `x = 'func_1'` how would I go about being able to say, call the utilities function from this string.

So for example, how would I get the result of this

```
utilities.func_1(var1, var2)
```

by typing something like this

```
x = 'func_1'
utilities.x(var1, var2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: yes, although I wont delete my question, as I feel the question is still relevant.